# reactJS and dynamic render with map function my data is repeating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am starting on an application which needs to dynamically generate input boxes based on a selection from a drop down.  This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Container, Row, Col, Input, Button, Fa, Card, CardBody } from "mdbreact";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numberOfUnits: 0,
      name: {
        valid: true,
        value: "",
        label: "Property Nickname",
        length: 0,
        css: "grey-text"
      },
      address: {
        valid: true,
        value: "",
        label: "Property Address",
        length: 0,
        css: "grey-text"
      },
      city: {
        valid: true,
        value: "",
        label: "Property City",
        length: 0,
        css: "grey-text"
      },
      numberOfUnits: {
        valid: true,
        value: "",
        label: "Property City",
        length: 0,
        css: "grey-text"
      }
    };

    this.saveData = this.saveData.bind(this);
    this.setUnitNumber = this.setUnitNumber.bind(this);
  }

  setUnitNumber() {
    let currentComponent = this;

    var localUnitCount = document.getElementById("inputNumberOfUnits").value;
    currentComponent.setState({ numberOfUnits: localUnitCount });
  }

  saveData() {
    let currentComponent = this;

    var validData = true;
    var localName = {
      valid: true,
      value: "",
      label: "Property Nickname",
      length: 0,
      css: "grey-text"
    };
    var localAddress = {
      valid: true,
      value: "",
      label: "Property Nickname",
      length: 0,
      css: "grey-text"
    };
    var localCity = {
      valid: true,
      value: "",
      label: "Property City",
      length: 0,
      css: "grey-text"
    };

    // validate the property nickname
    localName.value = document.getElementById("lblName").value;
    localName.length = localName.value.length;

    if (localName.length < 5) {
      validData = false;
      localName.valid = false;
      localName.label =
        "You did not enter a property nickname (minimum of 5 charaters)";
      localName.css = "text-danger";
    }

    // validate the property address
    localAddress.value = document.getElementById("lblAddress").value;
    localAddress.length = localAddress.value.length;

    if (localAddress.length < 3) {
      validData = false;
      localAddress.valid = false;
      localAddress.label =
        "You did not enter a property Address (minimum of 5 characters)";
      localAddress.css = "text-danger";
    }

    // validate the property city
    localCity.value = document.getElementById("lblCity").value;
    localCity.length = localCity.value.length;

    if (localCity.length < 3) {
      validData = false;
      localCity.valid = false;
      localCity.label =
        "You did not enter a property city (minimum of 3 characters)";
      localCity.css = "text-danger";
    }

    currentComponent.setState({
      name: localName,
      city: localCity,
      address: localAddress
    });
  }

  renderData = () => {
    let currentComponent = this;

    var localUnitCount = this.state.numberOfUnits;
    var idArray = [];
    var idObject = {
      counter: 0,
      idName: ""
    };

    for (var counter = 0; counter < localUnitCount; counter++) {
      var unitName = "Unit";
      if (counter < 10) {
        unitName = unitName + "0";
      }
      unitName = unitName + (counter + 1);
      idObject.counter = counter + 1;
      idObject.idName = unitName;
      idArray[counter] = idObject;
      console.log("idArray[counter]: ", idArray[counter]);
    }

    console.log(idArray);

    return idArray.map(item => (
      <div>
        <div className="oldscanFont">
          <label> Unit {item.counter} </label>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center position-absolute w-100 h-50 align-items-center align-content-center">
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col md="6">
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <form>
                      <p className="h4 text-center py-4">Sign up</p>
                      <div className={this.state.name.css}>
                        <Input
                          id="lblName"
                          label={this.state.name.label}
                          group
                          type="text"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className={this.state.address.css}>
                        <Input
                          id="lblAddress"
                          label={this.state.address.label}
                          group
                          type="text"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className={this.state.city.css}>
                        <Input
                          id="lblCity"
                          label={this.state.city.label}
                          group
                          type="text"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className={this.state.numberOfUnits.css}>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label
                              class="input-group-text"
                              for="inputNumberOfUnits"
                            >
                              Number of Units
                            </label>
                          </div>
                          <select
                            class="custom-select"
                            id="inputNumberOfUnits"
                            onChange={() => {
                              this.setUnitNumber();
                            }}
                          >
                            <option value="1" selected>
                              One
                            </option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                            <option value="11">Eleven</option>
                            <option value="12">Twelve</option>
                            <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
                            <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
                            <option value="15">Fifteen</option>
                            <option value="16">Sixteen</option>
                            <option value="17">Seventeen</option>
                            <option value="18">Eighteen</option>
                            <option value="19">Nineteen</option>
                            <option value="20">Twenty</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div>{this.renderData()}</div>
                      <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
                        <Button
                          color="cyan"
                          onClick={() => {
                            this.saveData();
                          }}
                        >
                          Save
                        </Button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When i run the code, and select 4 from the drop down, the application should dynamically generate 4 elements.  The code is not complete but for some reason, when I am building the array that gets sent to the map function, the array contains the same data in each instance.  Below is a screen shot of the application and the console.log after I selected 4 from the drop down:
[image]

As you can see from the console.log, it appears that the idArray is being build correctly but the final console.log shows all 4 instances of the idArray containing the same counter and idName values.  Then, when the render executes and I put out {item.counter}, each element contains the same value.

Any idea why this may be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: You're creating `var idObject` just once, before the loop. You need to make multiple objects, so move that code inside the loop

Comment: @NicholasTower You are correct.  I made the change at that worked.  But I'm not sure I understand why.  If I create idObject once outside the loop, why wouldnt the values just get over written each time through the loop and then assigned to the next instance of the idArray array?

Comment: They **do** get overwritten each time through the loop, which is why once everything is done, you see it log out Unit04. You've inserted the same object into the array 4 times, so you have 4 references to the exact same object.

Answer (score 0):

I find this part of `renderData` method rather interesting.

```
...
for (var counter = 0; counter < localUnitCount; counter++) {
  var unitName = "Unit";
  if (counter < 10) {
    unitName = unitName + "0";
  }
  unitName = unitName + (counter + 1);
  idObject.counter = counter + 1;
  idObject.idName = unitName;
  idArray[counter] = idObject;
  console.log("idArray[counter]: ", idArray[counter]);
}
```

`idObject` is being modified in place instead of as a copy.

This can be written as.

```
... 
var idNamePrefix = "Unit";
for (var counter = 0, unitName; counter < localUnitCount; counter++) {

  if (counter < 10) {
    unitName = idNamePrefix + "0";
  } else {
    unitName = idNamePrefix + (counter + 1);
  }

  idArray.push(
    // make object with idObject key-values applied.
    // more importantly, the last object replaces the count and idName value.
    Object.assign({}, idObject, {counter: counter + 1, idName: unitName})
  )
}
```